# How would I exclude directories using TFS Fortify Static Code Analyzer

Tags: tfs, fortify

SCA version 17.20.0183

I want to point out I am not a fortify professional, I am inheriting a system that I am required to use and am the only one here tasked with getting it to run, nobody else with experience on tfs or fortify around.

I am using TFS fortify plugin to scan my code from our repo. I am able to set the build parameters to only include a certain directory but what I would like to do is exclude a few directories that are inside of that directory.
As an example I have

C:\**\Test\A

C:\**\Test\B

C:\**\Test\C

C:\**\Test\D

I only wish to Scan A and D.

I have tried adding into the build field Source Files to translate an

-exclude "C:\**\Test\B"

-exclude "C:\**\Test\C"

The total amount of files in all of these folders is roughly 600 files. It usually takes about 15 minutes to scan all of the folders but when I set this it ran 30 Minutes or more and no visible signs of succeeding.

I also tried

-exclude "Test\B"

-exclude "Test\C"

This still scanned all of the files.

I am hoping I can skip whole directories with the TFS fortify plugin hoping someone can shed some light as to what I am doing wrong. I see there is a scan section below the build section with an entry that says Additional Scan Parameters. Should I be using that? If so how would I use that?

Build Definition

```
A. Build Tab
1. Run Fortify on
    SCA license file
    Build Id for Fortify SCA - FS-JAVA
    Run Fortify Rulepack Update - No
    Run Fortify Clean - Yes 
    SCA verbose - No
    SCA debug - No  

2. Build (translate)
    Run Build (translate) - Yes

    Application Type - Java
    Classpath
    Source Version - Java 1.8
    Sourcepath
    Additional Build Parameters
    Build Tool Options
    Source File(s) to translate - Source/Java
    Translation of any other miscellaneous files

3. Scan
    Run Fortify scan - Yes  
    Scan type - Local Scan
    Additional scan parameters
    Custom Rulepacks    
    Upload results to SSC - yes
    Fortify SSC server endpoint - Fortify
    SSC application name - FS_JAVA  
    SSC application version - Current_version
    Proxy URL
    Proxy Username
    Proxy Password
4. Control Options
    Enabled - Yes
    Continue on error - No
    Always run - No
    Timeout - 0

B. Option Tab
All unchecked

C. Repository
Type - Git
Clean - False
Label Sources - Don't label sources
Report build Status - Yes
Checkout submodules - No

D. Variables
Default Config

E. Triggers 
All unchecked

F. General
Default Setup

G. Retention
Default

H. History
History
```

Comment: Have you tried use `-exclude` rather than `exclude`? If the parameter you are using is `-exclude`, would you please share your build definition about this task and the arguments?

Comment: Which part of the build definition would you need? I have 8 tabs in TFS to sort through. Just asking so that I do not give you useless information.

Comment: Edited original post and added some information.